# Error in plotting the interefence of Laguerre-Gaussian (LG) beam

Tags: plotting, special-functions

```
     I am trying to plot the given below, however, I am not able to plot it. 

   w0 = 1200*10^-6; \[Lambda] = 532*10^-6; z0 = (Pi*w0^2)/\[Lambda]; wz =
   w0*Sqrt[1 + (z/z0)^2]; p = 0; l = 2; z = .015;
  A0 = Sqrt[(2*p!)/(Pi*(p + Abs[l])!)]*1/wz; \[Phi]g = 
  ArcTan[z/z0]; Rz = z (1 + (z0/z)^2); k = 2 Pi/\[Lambda];
 \[Theta] = Pi/6; n = 1.33; d = 0.003; \[CapitalDelta] = 2 \[Theta]*d/n;
 f[x_, y_, \[Phi]1_] := 
 A0*((Sqrt[(x^2 + y^2)]*Sqrt[2])/wz)^
 Abs[l] Exp[-(x^2 + y^2)/wz^2] LaguerreL[p, Abs[l], (2 (x^2 + y^2))/
 wz^2] Exp[(I Pi*(x^2 + y^2))/(\[Lambda]*Rz)] Exp[
I (2 p + Abs[l] + 1) \[Phi]g] Exp[I l \[Phi]1] Exp[
I k \[Lambda]/2];
  g[x_, y_, \[Phi]2_] := 
 A0*((Sqrt[(x^2 + (y + \[CapitalDelta])^2)]*Sqrt[2])/wz)^
 Abs[l] Exp[-(x^2 + (y + \[CapitalDelta])^2)/wz^2] LaguerreL[p, 
 Abs[l], (2 (x^2 + (y + \[CapitalDelta])^2))/wz^2] Exp[(
 I Pi*(x^2 + (y + \[CapitalDelta])^2))/(\[Lambda]*Rz)] Exp[
I (2 p + Abs[l] + 1) \[Phi]g] Exp[I l \[Phi]2] Exp[(
 I k*(x^2 + (y + \[CapitalDelta])^2))/(\[Lambda]*Rz)];
\[Phi]1 = ArcTan[x, y]; \[Phi]2 = ArcTan[x, (y + \[CapitalDelta])]; 
gh[x_, y_, \[Phi]_] := f[x, y, \[Phi]1] + g[x, y, \[Phi]2]; rx = 0.012;
DensityPlot[
 Evaluate[Abs@gh[x, y, \[Phi]1, \[Phi]2]], {x, -rx, rx }, {y, -rx, 
rx}, Mesh -> None, PlotPoints -> 100, PlotRange -> All, 
ImageSize -> {400, 400}, PlotRange -> All, 
PerformanceGoal -> {"Speed", "Quality"}, 
ColorFunction -> 
 Function[Blend[{Black, Red}, Rescale[#, {0.01, 1}]]], 
  Exclusions -> None, FrameTicks -> None]
```

Comment: Definition `gh[..]` has three arguments and you call it in `DensityPlot` with four!

Comment: You don't need `Evaluate[…]` if you use [immediate assignments `=`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Set.html) instead of delayed assignments `:=`.

Answer (score 3):

Wrong definition of `gh` plus wrong usage of wrong `gh` inside `DensityPlot`.

```
\[Phi]1 := ArcTan[x, y]
\[Phi]2 := ArcTan[x, (y + \[CapitalDelta])]

Clear[gh]
gh[x_, y_] := f[x, y, \[Phi]1] + g[x, y, \[Phi]2];

rx = 0.012;

DensityPlot[Evaluate[Abs @ gh[x, y]], {x, -rx, rx}, {y, -rx, rx},
 Mesh -> None,
 PlotPoints -> 100,
 PlotRange -> All,
 ImageSize -> {400, 400},
 PlotRange -> All,
 PerformanceGoal -> {"Speed", "Quality"},
 ColorFunction -> Function[Blend[{Black, Red}, Rescale[#, {0.01, 1}]]],
 Exclusions -> None]
```

[image]

An alternative:

```
rx = 0.0075;
DensityPlot[Evaluate[Abs@gh[x, y]], {x, -rx, rx}, {y, -rx, rx},
 PlotPoints -> 100,
 ImageSize -> 400,
 ColorFunction -> "DarkRainbow",
 Exclusions -> None]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @eldo, it's working.

Comment: My pleasure - if you are satisfied with the answer you can upvote it (click the upper triangle) and / or accept it (click the checkmark).